# Is it safe to mail a stock certificate?

Tags: share-certificate

The Company that issued the stock certificate was sold. The new company is not going to issue shares and wants the physical certificate before they send me the cash.

I was told by the new company to leave the line blank, and send in the certificate.
In my opinion, anyone could fill out the space with any name.

Also during this pandemic, how to send the document securely?

Comment: Country (and, if applicable, State) may help.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to mail a stock certificate?

> Also during this pandemic, how to send the document securely?

COVID hasn't closed post offices, UPS and FedEx. Thus, send it Registered Mail or via UPS/FedEx Overnight Letter